# Updating data in lm() calls

Tags: r, regression

Is there is an equivalent to update for the data part of an lm call object?

For example, say i have the following model:

```
dd = data.frame(y=rnorm(100),x1=rnorm(100))
Model_all <- lm(formula = y ~ x1, data = dd)
```

Is there a way of operating on the lm object to have the equivalent effect of:

```
Model_1t50 <- lm(formula = y ~ x1, data = dd[1:50,])
```

I am trying to construct some psudo out of sample forecast tests, and it would be very convenient to have a single lm object and to simply roll the data.

Comment: Why not just redo the `lm` call, as you are doing there?

Comment: @DavidRobinson, beacuse i want to pass the `lm()` object into a function and subset on the `$model`. Here's an example: `model_1t50_2 = update(Model_all, data = Model_all$model[1:50,])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that `update` actually does what you want!

```
example(lm)
dat1 <- data.frame(group,weight)
lm1 <- lm(weight ~ group, data=dat1)
dat2 <- data.frame(group,weight=2*weight)
lm2 <- update(lm1,data=dat2)
coef(lm1)
##(Intercept)    groupTrt 
##      5.032      -0.371 
coef(lm2)
## (Intercept)    groupTrt 
##     10.064      -0.742
```

If you're hoping for an effiency gain from this, you'll be disappointed -- R just substitutes the new arguments and re-evaluates the call (see the code of `update.default`).  But it does make the code a lot cleaner ...

Answer (score 1):

biglm objects can be updated to include *more* data, but not less. So you could do this in the opposite order, starting with less data and adding more. See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/biglm.pdf

However, I suspect you're interested in parameters estimated for subpopulations (ie if rows 1:50 correspond to  level `"a"` of factor variable `factrvar`. In this case, you should use interaction in your formula (`~factrvar*x1`) rather than subsetting to `data[1:50,]`.  Interaction of this type will give different effect estimates for each level of `factrvar`.  This is more efficient than estimating each parameter separately and will constrain any additional parameters (ie, `x2` in `~factrvar*x1 + x2`) to be the same across values of `factrvar`--if you estimated the same model multiple times to different subsets, `x2` would receive a separate parameter estimate each time.

Comment: +1, very helpful. I will most likely do that at some time, but in this case it was a much more vanilla requirement.